# Is it possible to deconstruct imports on babel 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

With babel 7, you can't really export your modules and deconstruct them anymore using babel syntax. Is there a plugin, old syntax, or something I'm missing that allows me to do the following?

```
// file1.js
export const x = 0;
export const y = 1;
export default z;

// file2.js
import { x, y } from './file1.js'
console.log(x); // output: 0
console.log(y); // output: 1
```

Comment: `import { x, y } from './file1.js'` is not destructuring, it's simply how you import named exports. Babel supports whatever is valid and since this is valid it is supported, [as you can see for yourself](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgDwDRwJ5wL5wGZQQhwDkAdAPR7AA2ApgIxkBWAziQNwBQAxhAHasI9MjQgBzABTIAlBzgUKcCAFcYYNQC44ABl4ChIsVIxyFS1eq1wGQA&presets=es2015&version=7.2.2).

Comment: Oh, I see. You can't do `const x` and then `export const x` or `export x`.

Comment: No. It's either `export const x = 42;` or `const x = 42; export {x};`. See the MDN documentation for more information about the syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to my problem with Felix help. My misunderstanding was very silly: the `export` will still declare whatever variable you define after it, like:

```
const x = 0;
export const x = 0; // this will be invalid, because x is a constant already
```

I kept getting syntax errors on my webpack and didn't understand that it was because I was declaring the variable twice, so I thought it was a problem with webpack or babel.